# Docker get service to run in background using docker-compose (neo4j in docker container on raspberry pi 4)

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get neo4j running inside a Docker container on raspberry pi.

I've managed to get it running natively on raspberry pi [based on instructions here](https://debian.neo4j.org/)

I can get it to run in an interactive shell, but if I try to run through docker-compose the container exits immediately.

i.e. `docker run -it -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j.rpi.1:latest /bin/bash` this works ok.

I presumably need some way of running the neo4j process in the background - but I can't work out how to

Grateful for any help with this.

Other points:

- I'm using a [balenalib image as the base](https://www.balena.io/docs/reference/base-images/base-images-ref/)
- There's an official [docker-neo4j github page](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/tree/master/docker-image-src/3.5), but I can't get this to build on raspberry pi.
- The `neo4j.conf` file that I'm copying over is the [default file](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/) with [remote access enabled](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-enable-remote-https-access-with-neo4j-30x/)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM balenalib/raspberry-pi-debian

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install neo4j

COPY neo4j.conf /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
EXPOSE 7474 7473 7687

CMD ["neo4j", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:rpi.1
    ports:
    - "7474:7474"
    - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
    - ./neo4j/data:/data
    - ./neo4j/logs:/NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level
    - ./neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
    - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/test
    entrypoint:
#      - bin
#      - bash
      - neo4j
      - start
```

error message:

```
Attaching to neo4j-rpi-docker_neo4j_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=neo4j-rpi-docker', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dneo4j-rpi-docker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0xb439eb30>
neo4j_1  | Active database: graph.db
neo4j_1  | Directories in use:
neo4j_1  |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j_1  |   config:       /etc/neo4j
neo4j_1  |   logs:         /var/log/neo4j
neo4j_1  |   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
neo4j_1  |   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
neo4j_1  |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j_1  |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j_1  |   run:          /var/run/neo4j
neo4j_1  | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j_1  | Started neo4j (pid 47). It is available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/
neo4j_1  | There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
neo4j_1  | See /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log for current status.
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('41fe8bd8dc4b84e56068fb9e274264333a6cc0c811f054a45fef0a98619eea1c')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('41fe8bd8dc4b84e56068fb9e274264333a6cc0c811f054a45fef0a98619eea1c')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/41fe8bd8dc4b84e56068fb9e274264333a6cc0c811f054a45fef0a98619eea1c/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 0}
neo4j-rpi-docker_neo4j_1 exited with code 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/41fe8bd8dc4b84e56068fb9e274264333a6cc0c811f054a45fef0a98619eea1c/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['start'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['neo4j', 'start'],
            'Env': ['NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test',
                    'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
```

Comment: Do you need an option to make it run in the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out, had to use the ["docker-entrypoint.sh" file here](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/blob/master/docker-image-src/3.5/docker-entrypoint.sh) and then have `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` in my `Dockerfile`